# Setting up Page Objects with python and seem to be getting every error possible

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, python, page-objects

Project structure:

```
WebTeam
    __init__.py
    BasePage.py
    UIMap.py

Pages:
    __init__.py
    Common.py
    ContactPage.py

test:
    __init__.py
    CompetitorsTest.py
    CreateAnonData.py
    CreateKnownData.py
```

The code:

```
import unittest
import time

from selenium                                       import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui                  import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains        import ActionChains
from BasePage                                       import BasePage
from UIMap                                          import tomcat8LoginPage, tomcat8urls, competitors

class test_Competitors(unittest.TestCase, BasePage):

def setup(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.get(tomcat8urls ['loginPageTomcat8'])

def test_Compete(self):
    driver = self.driver
    actions = ActionChains(driver)

    ### Log-in and navigate to Competitors page ###
    self.fill_out_field\
        ("id",
            tomcat8LoginPage ['usernameField'],'username2092')

    self.fill_out_field\
        ("id",
            tomcat8LoginPage['passwordField'],'Password2092')

    self.click\
        ("id",
            tomcat8LoginPage ['loginBtn'])

    driver.get(tomcat8urls ['newUIurl'])

    self. click\
        ("xpath",
            competitors ['inboundMenu'])
```

This is the latest error I have gotten:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CompetitorsTest.py", line 18, in test_Compete
  driver = self.driver
AttributeError: 'test_Competitors' object has no attribute 'driver'
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `setup` method should be `setUp` for unittest. I'm not sure why they decided to name it that way, but that's just how it is.

Since `setup` is not a keyword it's not getting called, thereby making `self.driver` throw an `AttributeError`.

But I did the same thing still not working for me any specific reasons ??

"from YFT_Pages.LogInPage import LogIn
from YFT_Pages.CreateAccount import CreateAccount
import unittest

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

```
@classmethod
def setUp(cls) -> None:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"E:\Doc & Sw\chromedriver.exe")

def test_LogIn(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("http://foottech.4thpointer.in/")

    createAccount = CreateAccount(driver)
    createAccount.user_Name("Shorya Kaushik")
    createAccount.user_Phone("8791517915")
    createAccount.user_Mail("Shorya@Test.com")
    createAccount.user_Password("123")
    createAccount.user_ConfPassword("123")
    createAccount.user_Role("Player")
    createAccount.user_submit()

    login = LogIn(driver)
    login.userMail("shorya@test.com")
    login.userPassword("123")
    login.submit()

@classmethod
def tearDown(cls) -> None:
    cls.driver.close()
    cls.driver.quit()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    unittest.main()

"